# Dynamically allocate memory using stack ( not heap ) in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

How can you dynamically allocate memory using stack ( not heap )?

Do they need different functions than `malloc()`,`calloc()` ? Which header file is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`alloca(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) is the function you're looking for.

```
void test_alloca(int num)
{
    int *myarray = alloca(num * sizeof(int));

    // do not try to free(myarray) !
}
```

In C99 you can also declare a [variable-length array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```
void test_vla(int num)
{
    int myarray[num];
}
```

These two code snippets are functionally identical. (An exception being that the first declares a pointer while the second declares an array, leading to different results if you take the `sizeof(myarray)`.)

Comment: Don't we need to do type casting in alloca ? and can't i declare variable length array when allocation is done on heap ? also i want to know why we need to allocate memory on stack for what reasons or can there be any situations where its must ??

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in your question

> *dynamically allocate memory using stack*

is a bit broad. However, In my opinion, you have two options,

1. Use [`alloca()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca), prototyped in `<alloca.h>`
2. Use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) <sup>C99 and above</sup>

But remember the fundamental difference, the lifetime of the allocated memory through aforesaid process will be limited by their scope.